# How to get information about unsent emails in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, data-views

I have a Journey Builder, in which there are exceptional situations where an email, in general, is not sent and these people are not counted in the Contact Count. They are also not in the Data View Send. How can I get a list of such contacts via SQL Query?

Answer (score 2):

The 'Not Sent' information in general in SFMC, is a little cumbersome to achieve. However, there are few approaches you could take in order to get the closest information.

1. Tracking Extract: You can set up a tracking extract in Automation Studio. There is an extract type '[Not Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_notsent.htm&type=5)', which can give you this information. However, tracking extracts sometimes don't give the best view and there is limited help and support on them.
2. SQL Method: This will not be very accurate, but worth giving a short. You can build a list of all customers from your sent data view, bounce and then subtract them from the total target DE. This will help you with a approximate number. But it has implications, if your target DE is getting overridden on a daily basis, sometimes bounce data takes 72 hours to update.

In general, SFMC has a list of contacts that they exclude, such as Global unsubscribes, contacts that have email address starting from 'info@'. They are excluded because of the [List Detective](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335444&type=1) feature.

Hope this helps.