# Import 'view details' data from Journey Builder activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have some errors in Journey Builder in email activity. Users who have wrong email address (e.g. invalid domain) exit the journey because of the recognize in the marketing cloud list detective. Those users have hard errors and can't get the next activities in line, because they exit the journey.

I would like to know how to import hard errors from journey builder activity? Is there any option in Marketing Cloud?

Comment: You are basically asking for the 'Not Sent' List of subscribers. Have a look at this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/384838/how-to-get-information-about-unsent-emails-in-journey-builder/384840#384840. FYI: Subscribers who are not sent due to invalid domains or incorrect email addresses get into the Bounce Data View.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the subscriber doesn't exist in the _Bounce Data View. I assume that hard errors in the journey builder email activity doesn't a kind of bounce, it's an error.